# For output weird

Tags: shell-script

This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
E=0;j=0
for i in A B C
do
  Erray=$(sed -n '/Local net energy/p' log | awk '{print $7}')
  A[j]=j
  echo $i = $Erray kJ/mol >> Energy
  let j=j+1
  echo $j $i $Erray ${A[j]}
done
cat Energy
```

The output is:

```
1 A 2.692036739192E+03
2 B 2.679751695663E+03
3 C 4.732453844269E+03
A = 2.692036739192E+03 kJ/mol
B = 2.679751695663E+03 kJ/mol
C = 4.732453844269E+03 kJ/mol
```

It should not be that. The order of the output is "sorted" and the `${A[j]}` doesn't appear.

**Edit** Now I know why the output is sorted. I forgot to add `>> Energy` after the second `echo`. The array problem still remains. My input data is large, I only extract lines which are relevant.

```
print energy 2 - 1 end
  Local net energy (PE 0) = 2.692036739192E+03 kJ/mol
  Global net ELEC energy = 2.692036739192E+03 kJ/mol
```

Comment: Could you give us some of your input data?

Comment: Turn on the debugging in Bash to see what's going on. Add a `set -x` right after `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: I have edit my post and add some data, please come and see. After adding `set -x`, nothing changes.

Comment: Please consider making these things functions rather than bash arrays...

Comment: @mikeserv: can you tell me why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your script, `j` is monotonically incrementing - it starts from 0 and counts up by one per iteration of the loop.  You assign a value to `A[j]` in your loop, then you increment `j`, then you try to print out `A[j]` - but now that `j` has been incremented, that index in `A` hasn't been set yet, so there's nothing to print (the variable expansion is empty).  If you were printing `${A[j-1]}` instead you should see output.

Comment: Or switch the lines: put before `echo $j $i $Erray ${A[j]}` and after `let j=j+1`

Comment: Ahhhh, yes. How stupid I am. Thank you so much.